# Who made now part of the problem?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math, math-history, education

Who came up with the meme of putting the current year as a four digit number into exercise problems?

Is there a known first historical account?

Comment: I think it's just the laziness of mathematicians writing homework problems. "*Hmmm, where can I find some large enough numbers to make the exercise almost impossible through brute-force calculations, without repeating the numbers from last year? Oh, I know! $2013^{2014}$ works just fine!*"

Comment: Not the current year, but [Felix Klein](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Klein.html) was born on 25/4/1849 and delighted in pointing out that each of the day ($5^2$), month ($2^2$), and year ($43^2$) was the square of a prime.

Comment: @PerManne: hehe.